# SQL query to check a date 2 weeks from today

Tags: php, mysql

We have a booking form, where users can book for several tours and for several tour dates. An order is created after they book and is set to 'pending' state. We want to process the order exactly 2 weeks before the tour date.

We wrote a cron job function and its intended purpose is to get all the orders which are in 'pending' state and there is exactly 2 weeks time for the tour date.

This is the query

```
$orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT o.*, b.departure_point, b.tour_date, b.tour_id FROM ".CT_TOUR_BOOKINGS_TABLE." b JOIN ".CT_ORDER_TABLE." o ON o.id = b.order_id WHERE o.status = 'pending' AND NOW( ) + INTERVAL 2 WEEK = b.tour_date");
```

The above line is not working, as we did some trial bookings. Is there anything wrong with the statement

```
"NOW( ) + INTERVAL 2 WEEK = b.tour_date"
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try now()+14? I tried something like this on oracle using sysdate+14 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you should user this to get two week interval

```
DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

you can change your date format as you need

Answer (score 0):

"NOW( ) + INTERVAL 2 WEEK = b.tour_date"

should be

"DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK) = b.tour_date"

instead

Answer (score 0):

If `tour_date` is a `datetime` field then it won't match `NOW( ) + INTERVAL 2 WEEK` as it will try to compare hours, minutes and seconds too. What you need to compare is `date` part only, try the following:

```
AND DATE(b.tour_date) =  DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)'s the documentation on MySQL's `DATE` function.

Comment: thanks for the reply, does this code work too?
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), b.tour_date) % 14 = 0

Comment: Nope, it will return all the dates that are 14,28,42.. and so on days from now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `DATEDIFF` instead:

```
"SELECT o.*,
        b.departure_point,
        b.tour_date,
        b.tour_id 
   FROM ".CT_TOUR_BOOKINGS_TABLE." b 
   JOIN ".CT_ORDER_TABLE." o 
     ON o.id = b.order_id 
  WHERE o.status = 'pending' 
    AND DATEDIFF(b.tour_date, today) = 14"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT o.*, b.departure_point, b.tour_date, b.tour_id FROM ".CT_TOUR_BOOKINGS_TABLE." b JOIN ".CT_ORDER_TABLE." o ON o.id = b.order_id WHERE o.status = 'pending' AND ((GETDATE()+14) = b.tour_date");
```

'now' is not a recognized built-in function name. Instead, use GetDate().

For reference
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic183904-8-1.aspx